# Missing fonts in Acrobat reader in wine

Tags: wine, fonts, adobe-reader, adobe-acrobat

I have managed to install Adobe Acrobat Reader (the only "free" PDF editor I could find) in wine. This is working, but a lot of texts are not being rendered.

I have run the following to install it (based on [this guide](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-install-latest-adobe-acrobat-reader-dc-on-ubuntu-18-04-bionic-beaver-linux-with-wine)):

```
winetricks mspatcha
wine path/to/installer.exe
```

I did fail and retry several times, so I may or may not have selected a 32-bit version.

Anyway, it works, but some fonts are missing. It is usable, but sometimes I really do miss the texts, eg in pop-up messages.

Does anyone know how to fix these fonts?

[image: Acrobat Reader running in wine]

Answer (score 16):

I just installed the latest version of Acrobat Reader DC (2019) in Wine using this guide by user filozofio [here](https://forum.manjaro.org/t/adobe-acrobat-reader-dc-2018-in-manjaro/49691) :

1. install `wine` and `winetricks`
2. execute these commands in a terminal:

   - `winetricks atmlib`
   - `winetricks riched20`
   - `winetricks wsh57`
   - `winetricks mspatcha`
3. Get the Windows 7 fonts, especially the `sego*` fonts.

   - I got them from here: https://www.w7df.com/7/download.html
4. Copy the windows fonts to a folder in `/usr/share/fonts`
5. execute this command in a terminal:

   - `sudo fc-cache -vf`
6. Download the Windows version of Adobe Acrobat Reader DC from https://get.adobe.com/reader/otherversions/
7. Install it via `wine`

   - `wine /path/to/installer.exe` (e.g. `wine ~/Downloads/AcroRdrDC1901020064_en_US.exe`
8. At start up, select "always start with protected mode disabled" (not possible in wine)
9. Accept the license

Comment: This way the microsoft fonts are installed on all users and globally (not only for wine programs). What should be changed to install them only in wine?

Answer (score 3):

To ensure that you have correct links to downloads update WineTricks as recommended on [its page](https://wiki.winehq.org/Winetricks).

```
wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Winetricks/winetricks/master/src/winetricks
chmod +x winetricks
```

And then place it in correct location

```
sudo cp winetricks $(which winetricks)
```

Then try to install all fonts with it:

```
winetricks allfonts
```

Comment: I had to run `wineserver --kill` first. Also, this failed with `sha256sum mismatch! Rename /home/remco/.cache/winetricks/PowerPointViewer/PowerPointViewer.exe and try again.`. I retried this several times yesterday and today.

Comment: I updated answer - you should download newer WineTricks. It seems that version from repository has broken links.

Answer (score 0):

As iwilltry42 says, but his answer contains loads of jargon(I beg my pardon). For me It worked like these:

1) simply installed Adobe Acrobat from the Ubuntu store.

2) Downloaded the Windows 7 fonts from https://www.w7df.com/7/download.html

3) Extracted it and pasted it in /usr/share/fonts(pate the entire extracted folder)

Bingo !

Note:- While pasting the file open file manager in super user mode(i.e - sudo nautilus)

Answer (score 0):

I used Play On Linux to install Acrobat Reader DC using predefined configuration available in Play On Linux. I choose option to automatically download Acrobat Reader DC and it was version 2015.

Some dialog windows in Acrobar Reader where completely missing text labels. I have downloaded a ZIP package with fonts for Windows 7 from https://www.w7df.com/p/windows-7.html and extracted all these fonts into a directory `PlayOnLinux's virtual drives/AdobeAcrobatReaderDC/drive_c/windows/Fonts` under my home folder.

This solved my problems with fonts in Acrobat Reader without polluting the `/usr/share/fonts` folder on my Linux Mint.