# Missing Hebrew fonts in Adobe Acrobat

Tags: wine, adobe-acrobat

I installed adobe via snap and it works fine. But when I try to fill a document and write with Hebrew, nothing shows. I tried installing 'culmus' in Ubuntu itself via apt, it didn't help. Any other pointers?

Update: If I type in Hebrew in a shell and then copy to Acrobat, the text shows up (but with a weird looking font [image]). So fonts are there, just can't type them directly

Comment: do you have Hebrew installed in the OS?

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1069103/missing-fonts-in-acrobat-reader-in-wine?rq=1

Comment: @Esther, yes, Culmus

Comment: no, not "a hebrew font", the Hebrew language + keyboard. Can you type in Hebrew in any other program?

Comment: https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-add-and-switch-keyboard-layout-on-ubuntu-22-04-desktop

Comment: @Esther yes I can (in any other Ubuntu program)